# Limit size of an image (up to 1 MB) while uploading

Tags: codenameone

I limit the height and width of the img in the code below (get the image from gallery and then upload), but i want to limit the image size(ie 1MB only, not width and height). More than 1 MB should display the warning. How can I get the size in bytes of image?

```
uploadImg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                try {
                    if (evt == null) {
                        System.out.println("user cancelled");
                        return;
                    }

                    eventImgpath = (String) evt.getSource();
                    Image i = Image.createImage(eventImgpath);
                    if (i.getWidth() < 800 && i.getHeight() < 267) {
                        eventImage.setIcon(i.scaledWidth(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()));
                    } else {
                        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Please check the size of the image: Height= 800 & Width= 267", 5000);
                    }
                    eventImage.getParent().revalidate();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit the size in bytes. As a workaround you can shrink the resolution and check the resulting size of the output file. E.g. for `FileSystemStorage` you can use the `getLength` method and for `Storage` you can use the `entrySize` method.